# Why is the largest scale window size is 14 in TCP?

Tags: networking, tcp

I am reading RFC1323, and I don't understand the following sentences,

```
TCP determines if a data segment is "old" or "new" by testing
      whether its sequence number is within 2**31 bytes of the left edge
      of the window, and if it is not, discarding the data as "old".  To
      insure that new data is never mistakenly considered old and vice-
      versa, the left edge of the sender's window has to be at most
      2**31 away from the right edge of the receiver's window.
```

What does "old" and "new" mean in the sentence?

I knew that the space size of sequence number in the current design is 2^32, so I understand that the scale size should be smaller then 32-16 = 16, but I don't understand why it should also be smaller than 15.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

TCP use sequence numbers to track data.  Higher sequence numbers are "newer" meaning they were originally sent at an earlier time. For example, if "hello" was sent, the "e" is newer than "h".  Since the sequence number range is finite, there needs to be a way to prevent "wrapping".  In this example, if the sequence range is 0 to 3, then "h" and "o" might have the same sequence number of 0.  So, in this example, if data is lost during transit and needs to be resent, then the receiver might end up getting "hellh".